# What does the "three A's arranged into a triangle" symbol mean on a laptop charger?

Tags: laptop, charger, label

A simple question: what does the encircled symbol mean? I can't quite find it through text search.

[image: label of a laptop charger with the "three A's arranged into a triangle" symbol, circled with a red freehand circle with drop shadow]
<sup>([image source](https://superuser.com/questions/1053996/electric-shocks-from-tip-of-laptop-charger-and-laptop-case-how-to-safely-test))</sup>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a Serbian "conformity mark", mostly equivalent to the European "CE" sign (that is, both have the same requirements).

- http://www.bsccentar.rs/index.php?page=tria_eng
- http://www.ratel.rs/regulations/rtte/about_rtte.582.html